# MVC Authentication Redirect to a New site C# (Windows authentication)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, windows-authentication

I want to redirect a user to a whole new site if they fail to login. I cannot find a good location in the application life cycle to do this or how to do this in MVC.

In the past we just put it in the page_load.

In mvc I use a custom authorized attribute and it works fine and redirects to the default 401 page. But I want to redirect to a whole new url or site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your custom authorize class you can do something like this (this may be MVC 5 only, I don't see it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx))

```
protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("http:\\someurl")
}
```

if that isn't available you have access to the HttpContext in AuthorizeCore

[RedirectResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.redirectresult.aspx) is detailed on msdn.